# CodeIgniter 4 URI Routing: - How to use regular expressions in '$routes->addPlaceholder(...)'

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-4

In CodeIgniter 4, it's possible to use Regular Expression patterns in your route definitions via custom placeholders.

I tried to make my URI route definitions more readable for development, but it doesn't work:

```php
$routes->group('files', ['namespace' => '\Modules\Files'], function ($routes) {
    $routes->addPlaceholder('userID', '(\d+)');
    $routes->addPlaceholder('firstFolderLetter', '[c|e|u|s|p]{1}');
    $routes->addPlaceholder('fileAction', '[o|d|r]{1}');
    $routes->addPlaceholder('fileID', '(\d+)');

    // How should this be? Doesn't work.
    $routes->get(
        'test/(:userID)/(:fileAction)/(:firstFolderLetter)/(:fileID)',
        'Files_Controller::getProjectFile/$1/$2/$3/$4'
    );

    // This one works.
    $routes->get(
        'test/(:userID)/(:any)/(:firstFolderLetter)/(:num)',
        'Files_Controller::getProjectFile/$1/$2/$3/$4'
    );
});
```

I can't get to my desired URL when I try the first URI route definition (*How should this be? Doesn't work*). If I insert the *"default"* routing parts it works fine.

I'm not an expert in regex. Maybe it's not possible to insert the same regular expression pattern (*'(\d+)'*) twice?

Comment: A bit off-topic, though I would recommend that you follow the [CodeIgniter Coding Style Guide](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/contributing/styleguide.md#naming-of-structural-elements) when naming classes/controllers. *Class names MUST be declared in PascalCase.*

Answer (score 0):

##### Solution

1. Instead of: ❌
   `$routes->addPlaceholder('userID', '(\d+)');`

Use this: ✅ `$routes->addPlaceholder('userID', '\d+');`

---

2. Instead of: ❌
   `$routes->addPlaceholder('fileID', '(\d+)');`

Use this: ✅ `$routes->addPlaceholder('fileID', '\d+');`

---

[Custom Placeholders](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html#custom-placeholders)

`$routes->addPlaceholder(placeholder: $placeholder, pattern: $pattern);`

*The second parameter of the `->addPlaceholder(...)` method **shouldn't** have parentheses wrapped around it.*